# Colorscheme becomes weird after re-installing Vim

Tags: colorscheme, microsoft-windows

I'm using vim on windows 10.

I just finished re-installing my Vim, without removing all of the installed plugins or even changing any configuriations in _vimrc.

now when i start vim, my colorscheme become like this:
[image: only text background changed]

however, if i move the cursor or scroll down to the last line, it became normal again.
[image: This was after i scroll to the bottom]

here's my _vimrc configuration:

```
filetype off
set shellslash
set rtp+=~/vimfiles/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin('~/vimfiles/bundle')
" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'sheerun/vim-polyglot' 
Plugin 'cocopon/iceberg.vim'
Plugin 'arcticicestudio/nord-vim'
Plugin 'Badacadabra/vim-archery'
Plugin 'kristijanhusak/vim-hybrid-material'
Plugin 'scheakur/vim-scheakur'
Plugin 'lifepillar/vim-solarized8'
Plugin 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
Plugin 'preservim/nerdtree'
Plugin 'preservim/tagbar'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plugin 'dyng/ctrlsf.vim'
" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line
filetype plugin indent on " Filetype auto-detection
set nu
syntax on
set cursorline
set showcmd
set showmode
" How many columns of whitespace a \t is worth
set tabstop=4 
" How many columns of whitespace a "level of indentation" is worth
set shiftwidth=4 
" Use spaces when tabbing
set expandtab
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set incsearch
set hlsearch
set termwinsize=10x0
set splitbelow
set mouse=a
let g:AutoPairsShortcutToggle = '<C-P>'
let NERDTreeShowBookmarks = 1 
let NERDTreeShowLineNumbers = 0
let NERDTreeMinimalMenu = 1
let NERDTreeWinSize = 31 
nmap <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
let g:tagbar_autofocus = 1
let g:tagbar_autoshowtag = 1
let g:tagbar_position = 'botright vertical'
nmap <F8> :TagbarToggle<CR>
set termguicolors
colorscheme solarized8
```

Comment: Welcome to vi SE. I can reproduce what you see running vim.exe from cmd. Every line touched by the cursorline retains the backgroundcolor. Redrawing with `<C-L>` only gives background behind text. This is really ugly.

Comment: Can you please add more information? What terminal? what is $TERM? What is `:set t_Co? termguicolors? t_ut? term?` Wild guess: Does `:let &t_ut=''` fix it?

Comment: if you have a problem with a third-party colorscheme, then the first step would be to use its issue tracker. Hopefully with better information.